# Create a Model Object from JSON/Dictionary without Objective-c Runtime & hard coding or keys

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, macos, cocoa

I am trying to parse a JSON and create a Model(a nested class structure). I can do it using JSONModel (available on Github) but I do not want to use Obj-c Runtime.

Is there any other way to achieve this? Lets see what I did with some dummy code.

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"personalDetail":@{@"name":@"Anoop kumar vaidya",
                                                   @"dob":@"3 Aug 1981",
                                                   @"sex":@"Male"},
                             @"workDetail":@{@"current":@"Photon",
                                               @"y2014":@"TechM",
                                               @"y2012":@"Exilant",
                                               @"y2010":@"RSG"},
                             @"educationDetail":@{@"pg":@"Mca - 63%",
                                                    @"ug":@"Bca -63%",
                                                    @"s12":@"58%",
                                                    @"s10":@"66%"
                                                    }
                             };


self.model = [[MainModel alloc] initWithMainModel:dictionary];
```

Implementation of `MainModel`, here you see the keys are hard coded. I want to avoid it, to make it generic.

```
-(id)initWithMainModel:(NSDictionary *)dict{

    for (NSString *key in dict) {
        [self putValue:dict[key] forKey:key];
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)putValue:(NSDictionary *)value forKey:(NSString *)key{

    if ([key isEqualToString:@"personalDetail"]) { 
        self.personalDetail = [[Personal alloc] initWithDictionary:value];
    }
    else if ([key isEqualToString:@"workDetail"]){
        self.workDetail = [[Work alloc] initWithDictionary:value];
    }
    else if ([key isEqualToString:@"educationDetail"]){
        self.educationDetail = [[Education alloc] initWithDictionary:value];
    }
}
```

Implementation of `Personal`. Similarly other two classes, `Work` & `Education` are implemented.

```
-(id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict{

    for (NSString *key in dict) {
        [self putValue:dict[key] forKey:key];
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)putValue:(NSString *)value forKey:(NSString *)key{
    [self setValue:value forKey:key];
}
```

Comment: I might have misunderstood something, wouldn't using `setValue: forKey:` work in this case, like you do on `Personal`?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by *not* using Objective-C runtime.  Everything is built on top of frameworks, which is the runtime.  But I assume you mean you want to be able to dynamically deserialize the model, without knowing any details of it?  This will definitely involve the runtime, as you won't know the method selectors you dispatch to until you know the (types of) properties that your model may contain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the key and extract the class name of it. Then you get the class for this identifier witch `NSClassFromString()` to get the class and instantiate it with `+alloc` as usual:

```
key = …;
if ([key hasSuffix:@"Detail"]) 
{
  NSString *className = [key substringToIndex:[key length]-[@"Detail length]];
  className = [[[className substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString] stringByAppendingString:[className substringFromIndex:1]];
}

id instance = [[NSClassFromString( className ) alloc] initWithDictionary:…];
```

I said: You *can* do it this way. I did not say: You *should*.

Comment: It won't work. In the sample you made out that the "suffix" is same, but it not always.

Comment: Of course not, if the suffix changes. There is no `NSGuessClassName` in Objective-C. This is, what you posted in your Q. If you have different naming rules, you have to adopt the code. You can add a look-up array to store key-classname pairs.